# Is it possible to change the class of multiple columns in a dataframe based on their current class?

Tags: r, class, for-loop, apply, multiple-columns

I have a large dataframe with 500+ columns with a variety of classes in a variety of orders. Example data:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
 2      red      1.2      5       5      5.7
 4     banana    2.3      0       6      5.2
 8      two      2.4      9       8      5.4
 2     first     1.6      7       9      5.9
```

I am trying to change the class of the columns based on what their current class is. For example, I want too change every column that is currently class "integer" to class "numeric", but leave all the columns that are currently class "character" untouched. Is this possible?

I tried using a for loop, but when I set it up this way, it reads the column classes as "data.frame" instead of "numeric".

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  ifelse(class(df[,i])=="integer",
         as.numeric(df[,i]),NA)
}
```

I also tried to use apply but couldn't figure out how to code the condition correctly or have it loop through only some of my columns without creating a vector specifically naming all the columns with the class type I want changed.

```
cols <- colnames(df[,which(is.Class("integer"))])
df[,cols] = apply(df[,cols], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x));
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this and if so, how? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ifelse` is made for vectors and requires that the length (or shape) of the result is the same as the length (or shape) of the input. It works great when you have a vector as input and want a modified vector as output.

In this case, you want to change the class of a column, so we want `if(){}else{}` not `ifelse()`.

Also, it's much safer to use `is.class` functions (like `is.integer`, `is.numeric`) than `class ==` to check a class--this is because an object can have multiple classes.

Lastly, it can be slightly safer to refer to a single column of a data frame as `data[[col]]` than `data[, col]`. The `[[` ensures that we get a single column out *as a vector*, not a 1-column data frame. ("tibbles" and other data.frame-like objects have different behavior with `data[, col]`, but `data[[col]]` is safe.)

Making those fixes to your `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if(is.integer(df[[i]])) {
    df[[i]] <- as.numeric(df[[i]])
  }
}
```

We could do `lapply` as well:

```
int_cols <- sapply(df, is.integer)
df[int_cols] <- lapply(df[int_cols], as.numeric)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your solutions worked for what I was trying to do, and I appreciate the general tips on how to code more effectively!

Answer (score 2):

The `across` function in `dplyr` can be very helpful here. Try something like:

```r
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, across(where(is.integer), as.numeric))
```

Comment: Beginning users of R may be puzzled with this solution since it will not affect the `df` object.

Comment: Because the OP used the assignment operator `<-` in their question, I assumed they would know how to reassign the output to that df or another df. From your experience, is this an unreliable assumption to make?